# How to verify that data source is valid and configured properly?

Tags: spring, hibernate, datasource

In application start up , I am loading data source as shown below code -

```
@Bean(name = "dataSource")
public DataSource getDataSource() {
    ComboPooledDataSource dataSource = new ComboPooledDataSource ();
    dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/usersdb");
    dataSource.setUsername("root");
    dataSource.setPassword("secret");
    return dataSource;
}
```

So here I would like to verify that whether the data source loaded properly, 
One possible way could be **datasource.getConnection()** before return but here I have to create  unnecessary connection object which is having some high cost.

Please help me to find a way to verify that data source has been instantiated properly. I have heard something about validate query but not sure how it would work. please suggest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is impossible to validate `DataSource` without test connection.

First of all, you define bean with singleton scope by default so single `DataSource` will be created with single check.

Secondly, do not worry about the creation cost of `Connection` because you use `PooledDataSource`. *'Pooled'* means that pool of connections exists that is why physical connection once created can be used many times by the application.

The *validate query* (or *test query*) is used to check if existing `Connection` was broken. See [Configuring Connection Testing](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#configuring_connection_testing) for more details.